# how to get target element id from @HostListener, angular2 directive

Tags: angular

my directive hostlistener code is

```
  @HostListener('mouseenter',['$event']) onMouseEnter(event) {
    this.highlight(this.highlightColor || this._defaultColor);
    console.log(event.target);
  }
```

and my element is

```
<div myHighlight [highlightColor]="'green'"  [defaultColor]="'violet'" id='dummyDiv'>
  some text
</div>
```

everything is working perfectly.

I just wanted to know that can I get element ID (#dummyDiv) in event.target in @HostListener?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
event.currentTarget.id
```